# JavaScript + Chrome: String.fromCharCode giving extraneous characters?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Can anyone explain why Chrome might be giving me this strange result? Defining,

```
var chars = [72, 101, 108, 108, 111, 44, 32, 119, 111, 114, 108, 100, 33];
```

this works just fine:

```
console.log(String.fromCharCode.apply(null,chars));
```

> Hello, world!

But

```
console.log(chars.map(String.fromCharCode));
```

returns

> ["H", "e", "l", "l", "o", ",", " ", "w", "o", "r  ", "l↵", "d", "!"]

I didn't encounter this behavior in IE. The `"r "` is a tab character. It seems that Chrome will do this at the same position no matter what the input array/string is.

Comment: The array index is passed as the 2nd argument to `String.fromCharCode` which interprets it as a character code, as `fromCharCode` is a variadic function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The callback to [`[].map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) receives three arguments: the current array item value, its index and the array itself. [`String.fromCharCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode) is a variadic function, hence it interprets all arguments as character codes.

That is, in the first iteration, you probably expect to get `String.fromCharCode(72)` (which is `'H'`), but in fact you're getting `String.fromCharCode(72, 0, chars) === 'H\x00\x00'`.

You can pass a callback function to ensure that only the array values are mapped to characters:

```
chars.map(function(charCode) {
    return String.fromCharCode(charCode);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget that [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) does pass 3 arguments to its callback: The item, the index, and the array. That's the reason why you get `"r\u0009"` and `"l\u000a"` (or better known as `"r\t"` and `"l\n"`) back in your array, from calls like `String.fromCharCode.call(null, 114, 9, chars)` and `String.fromCharCode.call(null, 108, 10, chars)`. The other strings will have a length of 2 as well, you just cannot see all those weird [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ascii#ASCII_control_characters) in the output.

Comment: Thanks! Just wanted to acknowledge you were first :) I gave the answer to Fabricio because I found his callback suggestion especially helpful, though your answers were essentially the same